# WP Query Category Atribute Not Working

Tags: wp-query, single

I'm trying to do a query in my `index.php` page to get some posts from my `blogue` category.

In my other pages this query works perfectly but on the `index.php` returns the most recent post 3 times.

They query:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'cat'         => '',
    'category_name'    => 'blogue',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'fields'           => '',

);
$wqBlog = get_posts($args);
```

the html:

```
<section class="container"> 
<div class="cards display--flex ">
            <?php foreach ($wqBlog as $blogPost): setup_postdata( $blogPost ); ?>
            <div class="card">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( ))  : ?>
                <div class="card__image display--flex">
                    <!--imagem -->
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
                </div> <!-- imagem -->
                <?php else : ?>
                <div class="card__image__none">
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <div class="card__container">
                    <p class="card__container__subtitle">
                        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                    </p>

                    <h2 class="card__container__title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>         
        </div> 

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of get_posts, why don't you use WP_Query instead?

I removed a few arguments because they are the default and can be omitted.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'category_name'    => 'blogue',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
);
$wqBlog = new WP_Query($args);
```

And in your HTML

```
<?php if( $wpBlog->have_posts() ): ?>
<section class="container"> 
<div class="cards display--flex ">
            <?php while ( $wqBlog->have_posts() ): $wpBlog->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="card">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( ))  : ?>
                <div class="card__image display--flex">
                    <!--imagem -->
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
                </div> <!-- imagem -->
                <?php else : ?>
                <div class="card__image__none">
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <div class="card__container">
                    <p class="card__container__subtitle">
                        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                    </p>

                    <h2 class="card__container__title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>         
        </div> 

</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I was using wp_query but it was causing me an error , not a fatal one, but one that was appearing on my console (something about the version of my wordpress)... I switched the while cicle for a for each one due to the infinite cycles i would cause sometimes... but i guess i'll give it a try thanks for your answer !

Comment: `WP_Query` can't put things in your browser console, that will be something in javascript doing that, not PHP

Comment: Did that work @PedroFerreira?

Comment: yes , but i was also not closing one of my while cycles ! thanks a lot sorry i completly forgot !!

Comment: Cool! I'm glad to help. Please mark this as the accepted answer if that was the case. Thank you.